# Scrollview is not working when a linear layout inside it

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

> I just put a linear layout inside a scrollview dont know why its not working.

When the keyboard is open the scrollbar is not showing at all. When i move one text box to another there is a submit button which is not show when i run on small size devices.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutPopUp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:background="#F57F20"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/backlayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnBackbutton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/back"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textBack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Back"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTitle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Contact Us"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imagePopUp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/menu"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/editboxshap"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#2b2b2b"
                android:textColorHint="#2b2b2b"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@color/black">

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editPhone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/editboxshap"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Phone No."
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="12"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#2b2b2b"
                android:textColorHint="#2b2b2b"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/editboxshap"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="E-mail"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#2b2b2b"
                android:textColorHint="#2b2b2b"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editComment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/editboxshap"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:hint="Comments"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="3"
                android:maxLength="500"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#2b2b2b"
                android:textColorHint="#2b2b2b"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@color/black" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                android:text="SUBMIT"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if all components of your layout exceeds screen height then scrollview comes in to play

Comment: Are you saying keyboard is hiding the view or else?

Comment: i don't think 4 EditText and a button fill the screen. Any way try to put `ScrollView` inside a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @Sanoop - yes keyboard is hiding the view..:(

Comment: i assume after the keyboard is open then also you can see all your layout elements . none are hidden due to the soft keyboard. in that case the scrollview will not scroll as there is no need of it. when some view are not visible due to its length at that time scrollview comes to play with its scrollbars.

Comment: I have tested your layout @SudhansuSekhar this is fine . and working all right with scrollview. its just starts scrolling when some part of screen is not visible. not always .

Comment: its not @sagar when keyboard is open then the button part is not visible in portait mode , at that time when i scroll the screen then then nothing happened but same thing when i rotate the screen i.e in landscape mode the scrollbar visible and it works fine

Comment: so it is having problem in portrait mode ? and works fine in landscape mode ?

Comment: yes exactly..:(@sagar

Comment: is it all your xml ? or you have not posted some lines . please post all the xml cods here .

Comment: Sagar i have updated my code, its all please help me

Answer (score 0):

try to put scrollview inside another linear layout and try

Answer (score 0):

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentLin"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="//define in dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/editboxshap"
        android:textColorHint="#2b2b2b"
        android:textColor="#2b2b2b"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/editboxshap"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#2b2b2b"
        android:hint="Phone No."
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textColorHint="#2b2b2b"
        android:maxLength="12"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/editboxshap"
        android:textColor="#2b2b2b"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColorHint="#2b2b2b"
        android:hint="E-mail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editComment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/editboxshap"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textColor="#2b2b2b"
        android:hint="Comments"
        android:textColorHint="#2b2b2b"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLength="500"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
    android:text="SUBMIT"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and You have to specify the following line of code in the manifest file with your activity

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: if all views of your layout exceeds your device height then scrollview will work !

Comment: Thanks saurabh for your answer but i just saw a thing that when i rotate the phone then in landscape mode the scrollview is working so this code is correct but dint know why in portait mode its not working..:(

Comment: @SudhansuSekhar...as i already mentioned in comment that  
if all views of your layout exceeds your device height then scrollview will work ! ....if my answer is right then upvote it...

Comment: @SudhansuSekhar..that'swhy scrollview was not working that time

Comment: No my brother in portait view also it should work , i also did this on my other apps but dont know , i think i am missing some thing thank you for your help..:)

Answer (score 0):

try This.. on your activity / fragment

```
getActivity().getWindow()
        .setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE |
                          WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: Thanks but not helpful